# Have review permissions changed?

Tags: discussion, review

I was looking at some New user answers in the review queue but found that I now have only two options as a response: "No Action Needed" or "Skip". There is a third option button of "I'm done", but it's greyed out.

Is that -- either a "thumbs up" or a "shrug" but nothing else -- how it should be? I seem to remember also being able to edit to improve or some other such option.

Answer (score 4):

The "I'm done" option becomes enabled **after you actually *do* something** with that post: e.g. **vote it up, or vote it down, or flag it** ... I forget whether **leaving a comment** without voting is enough  to enable "I'm done".

"No Action" means 'shrug' (it's OK but no upvote and no downvote) and "Skip" doesn't even mean that.

And/or if you want to edit the answer, you can: the 'edit' button is in its usual place i.e. **underneath (at the bottom-left of)** the answer, between the 'share' and 'flag buttons.